# All views's title not displaying

Tags: views

When viewing a page, the page title is empty.
In page tpl, page title isn't printed

```
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
    <?php if ($title): ?>
    <?php if ($title_hidden): ?><div class="element-invisible"><?php endif; ?>
    <h1 class="title" id="page-title"><?php print $title; ?></h>
    <?php if ($title_hidden): ?></div><?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Pls check ur question you have a mistake in </h1> tag as just </h>

Comment: Sorry I add </h1> but title not displayed